# I can't get UITextView to scroll to its bottom before UIViewController appears

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a UIViewText that I have in all my UIViewControllers that carries over data from the entire app's instance.

If I put the 2 lines that scroll to the bottom in the viewDidAppear section, the text scrolls to the bottom, but you see it occur, so it's not pleasant visually.

However, if I put the same 2 lines in the viewWillAppear section (as shown below) then for some reason the UITextView starts at the top of the text.
Am I somehow doing this incorrectly?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        myStatusWin.text = db.status
        let range = NSMakeRange(myStatusWin.text.count - 1, 0)
        myStatusWin.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

p.s. I have posted this question here, https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715382, but no responses